# How does Pratibhasik satya play out when it comes to perception of others?

Tags: philosophy, advaita, brahma-sutras, indriyas

So I assume my perception of others will not be vyavahirka Satya as it is not empirical and requires use of Mann, buddhi and anubhav. In other words more than what is possible by Gyan and karm indriya.

So question is how does it reveal itself ? After all perception of others will keep changing

Comment: The day where perception ends, TRUTH is revealed.